# Symfony 2 doctrine one-to-many relational mapping stumped

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm getting an error 'Error: Call to undefined method Login\LogBundle\Entity\User::getToken() '
when try to get the data from the another entity apiuserdetails.  The user_id is the foreign key in apiuserdetails.  I've been following the example http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html relational mapping model.  I am able to get information from the user entity using getRepository("LoginLogBundle:UserApiProfile") but if doing it in reverse as they describe I get the error. I'm doing something wrong with the mapping but can't see it.  would appreciate some help thanks.

controller code is

```
     namespace Login\LogBundle\Controller;
     use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
     use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
     use Login\LogBundle\Entity\User;
     use Login\LogBundle\Entity\UserApiDetails;
     use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
     use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

    class DefaultController extends Controller
    {

     public function userprofileAction(Request $request) {



     if ($request->getMethod()=='POST') {

    $name=$request->get('name');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $repository = $em->getRepository("LoginLogBundle:User");

    $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('username'=>$name));


    return $this->render('LoginLogBundle:Default:userprofile.html.twig',array('token'  => $user->getToken()));        

    }
    }

    else {
       return $this->render('LoginLogBundle:Default:userprofile.html.twig');  
    }


 }
```

}

Entity - User

```
        namespace Login\LogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Login\LogBundle\Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 *
 * User
 */
class User{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserApiDetails", mappedBy="User")
     */
    protected $userapidetails;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userapidetails = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return User
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */

    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string 
     */

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Entity - ApiUserDetails

```
        namespace Login\LogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Login\LogBundle\Entity\Repository    \UserApiDetailsRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_api_details")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * 
 * UserApiDetails
 */
class UserApiDetails{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $apiScheme;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $apiUrl;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $token;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $tokenSecret;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $apiId;

    /**
     * @var \Login\LogBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User",inversedBy="userapidetails")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */ 
    protected $user;

    /**
     * Set apiScheme
     *
     * @param string $apiScheme
     * @return UserApiDetails
     */
    public function setApiScheme($apiScheme)
    {
        $this->apiScheme = $apiScheme;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get apiScheme
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getApiScheme()
    {
        return $this->apiScheme;
    }

    /**
     * Set apiUrl
     *
     * @param string $apiUrl
     * @return UserApiDetails
     */
    public function setApiUrl($apiUrl)
    {
        $this->apiUrl = $apiUrl;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get apiUrl
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getApiUrl()
    {
        return $this->apiUrl;
    }

    /**
     * Set token
     *
     * @param string $token
     * @return UserApiDetails
     */
    public function setToken($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get token
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getToken()
    {
        return $this->token;
    }

    /**
     * Set tokenSecret
     *
     * @param string $tokenSecret
     * @return UserApiDetails
     */
    public function setTokenSecret($tokenSecret)
    {
        $this->tokenSecret = $tokenSecret;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tokenSecret
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTokenSecret()
    {
        return $this->tokenSecret;
    }

    /**
     * Get apiId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getApiId()
    {
        return $this->apiId;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \Login\LogBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return UserApiDetails
     */
    public function setUser(\Login\LogBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \Login\LogBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get the `\Login\LogBundle\Entity\User` you don't have the `setToken` and stated in the error message. And since you don't have a navigation property to the `\Login\LogBundle\Entity\UserApiDetails` you are, in fact, stuck if you go in this direction. Either you have a navigation property from the `User`, to fetch the (single or list) `UserApiDetails`, or you fech the `UserApiDetails` and use the navigation property to get the `User` information. In this last case you can simply use in the twig `{{ userapi.user.token }}`

Comment: I thought the navigation property you mention is done like below or can you give me the correct code please /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserApiDetails",   mappedBy="User")
     */
    protected $userapidetails;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userapidetails = new ArrayCollection();
    }    @saamorim

Comment: If must explicit implement the accessor to the userapidetails like `getUserapidetails()` and `setUserapidetails(UserApiDetails $userapidetails)` in order to work with the navigation in the api. Anyway, remember that you're getting an array of userapidetails, so beware of that in the twig since the `{{user.userapidetails}}` will return an array.

Comment: Thanks we're getting there slowly, I don't know how to render this array in the twig I do this in the controller  return $this->render('LoginLogBundle:Default:userprofile.html.twig',array('details' => $user->getUserapidetails()));   then in the twig    {%for find in details%} 
       {{ find.token }}
    {%endfor%}   get nothing @saamorim

Comment: Do a {{ dump(details) }} a see what the twig returns, then go from there.